# TFS after change port, how the project connect back to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Previously the project was using default port(8080), but because of some reason, we change the port to other port number. After that how we going to configure the project point to the new port? Because once we open the project, it will automatically connect to port 8080(the previous port number)

Or can i edit the SccTeamFoundationServer parameter under the .sln file?
This cannot achieved, when open the project it still prompt missing the connection.

I found a way to connected it.
under the source control explorer, add the new server / port.
everything going well again.

Comment: so you've answered it yourself?

Comment: I hope can get the better solution about this kind of situation. any idea? :)